# How do I avoid using the && logical operator in mapStateToProps in Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, logical-operators

When I'm selecting nested state in a selector I have to resort to using the `&&` logical operators

```
const mapStateToProps = store => ({
  image: store.auth.user && store.auth.user.photoURL;
});
```

Not using it breaks the app since the data comes from a network request and takes a second to show up.

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'photoURL' of null`

Is there a better way to do this or am I supposed to be using && everywhere? It looks messy and feels hacky.

Comment: A ternary?  Or if you are amenable to outside libraries, [lodash `get`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#get) achieves this relatively elegantly.

Comment: Thanks. _get looks nice. So just to confirm logical operators and ternaries are the standard way to do this?

Comment: How is `foo ? foo.bar : undefined` any more or less messy or hacky than `foo && foo.bar`? How would you measure better?

Comment: I don't think its better. I'll stick to my &&. I guess the question I was really asking is whether there is anything wrong with doing that, but it seems that the way everyone does it.

Comment: Optional chaining look fantastic though, better in the sense that it's clear and it uses fewer characters.

Comment: It's a matter of preference.  You could use `if` blocks instead, but it would be way less succinct.  Ternaries and logical operators fit on one line, but they tend look a bit ugly.  Also, if you find yourself doing this quite a bit, you could always write yourself a small utility to take care of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `?` operator

```
image: store.auth.user ? store.auth.user.photoURL : undefined
```

or you can use `||`

```
image:  ( store.auth.user || {} ).photoURL
```

There's a propsal for [**optional chaining**](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining) in JS `?`

```
var street = user.address?.street
```

Comment: Thank you. To confirm, logical operators and ternaries are the standard way to do this?

Comment: @JoshPittman optional chaining  still it is `stage 1` at present, you can use [babel-plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-optional-chaining) for this, but ternary and logical operator are standard

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
const mapStateToProps = ({ auth }) => ({ image: auth.user ? auth.user.photoURL : null });
```

There's also the `||` operator (`/*...*/ image: (auth.user || {}).photoURL`), but it's in the eye of the beholder if that's less hacky.

And if you need to do that in more than one place, you can always use a library like lodash or just implement a version of _.get.

Comment: Thank you. To be clear, logical operators and ternaries are the standard way to do this?